# Is it possible to Use Vuforia Simulator with Color?

Tags: vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I'm developing an app using Model Target. I don't have access to the model to test on it. The people with access to the model were enable to send me a recording that fits Vuforia's criteria.

I'm trying to now use Vuforia Simulator mode but when I test using the simulator, my model is not in Color and it's hard to position elements correctly.

Best,
Ines

I tried recording mode but it wasn't accepting the videos I was provided with. Now I want to mvoe to Simnukator but it's not working with colors.

Comment: Hard to understand what is going on here from your description. First, there is no Vuforia product called "Vuforia Simulator". Perhaps you mean "Recording and Playback"? Or "Session Recorder"?